# Test whether fortran is installed on OSX

Tags: installation

On OSX. How might I test whether fortran is installed on my machine?

```
$ fortran
-bash: fortran: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot depends on the operating system that you're running.  The error message that you included in your indicates that you're running the "bash" shell, which is most commonly seen on Linux systems.  The most commonly used Fortran compiler on such systems is the GNU fortran compiler, which you would invoke by

```
$ gfortran
```

Try issuing that command to see what happens.  If you get

> gfortran: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.

then you've got gfortran installed on the system.

There are of course many other fortran compilers available for Linux systems, including compilers from Intel and the Portland Group.  Another useful test would be to issue the command

```
$ man -k fortran
```

which should give you a list of man page entries related to Fortran.  It's likely that this will help you identify any other Fortran compilers that might be on your system.

Comment: If something screwy has happened, and a Fortran compiler is on the machine but the directory containing the compiler isn't in the user's `PATH`, then this method will fail. As a backup, you could check to see if gfortran is installed by running `find / -name gfortran` (note, to search all directories, you will need to run this command as `sudo` or root). In order to exhaustively check your computer for fortran compilers, you would also need to check for the names of other Fortran compiler executables (`ifort` for the Intel Fortran Compiler, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The bash command `apropos` followed by a keyword will search for commands that match the string you pass to it, provided that they're installed in your `$PATH`. Running `apropos fort` would find either `gfortran` or `ifort` if you have them, but Macs don't have any fortran compiler by default.

Answer (score 0):

This will list all the compilers installed: `dpkg --list | grep compiler`
Check if Fortan appears in the list or not.

Comment: -bash: dpkg: command not found

Comment: `dpkg` is not a command that is available on OS X.

Comment: Elegant solutions like these dont work on OS X :) Btw dpkg only knows about compilers installed from the repo/debs and anything installed by a sysadmin/user locally wont show up.